# How can a local web app interact with Chrome extension?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jquery-plugins

Can I send my values (key words) from DB to [Multi-highlight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji) Chrome extension?

My requirement is to open a given web page and highlight multiple key words. 
I will have an input field where URL is pasted, and keywords come from MySQL database.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-extension messaging is possible in chrome extension.

Sending a message to another extension is similar to sending one within your extension.

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var laserExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, {getTargetData: true},
  function(response) {
    if (targetInRange(response.targetData))
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, {activateLasers: true});
  });

// Start a long-running conversation:
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(laserExtensionId);
port.postMessage(...);
```

The extension you want to communicate must also have to listen your messages using `runtime.onMessageExternal` or `runtime.onConnectExternal` methods. .

Read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external) official documentation describing Cross-extension messaging in details.

Comment: I want all the keywords in the extension search bar on load , is this possible ?